# Downgrade SharePoint 2010 from Enterprise to Standard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a way to downgrade a SharePoint 2010 Server from Enterprise to Standard version, preserving all contents and profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From everything I've read, it is not possible to downgrade a farm.  You can, however turn off any Enterprise features that you do not wish to use.

If that is not a solution then you will need to build a new farm using Standard and then copy your existing Content Databases to that farm and attach them to web applications there.

Comment: If you go do reinstall standard make sure to deactivate all the enterprise features before you shut down the old farm before migrating the content database. If you had used enterprise features and try and move it to a standard install items could possibly break.