# Sharepoint 2013: how do I know if I am using server or enterprise?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm setting up a new SharePoint 2013 site, and I'm currently using an internal license from our Microsoft partnership on a dev server. I need to get a full license to use for a public facing external production server, but a question has been raised about some of the features I'm using, that we may not be licensed to use.

How can I find out if my dev server is using 2013 Server Standard or Server Enterprise?

I checked my site collection features and searching the page for "enterprise" I see that none of the 4 features are enabled. Is that all I need to do? seems too basic of a check.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Central Admin -> Upgrade and Migration --> Convert Farm License Type you can see your Current License.

Under Enable Enterprise Features (also in Upgrade and Migration) you can see which Feature Set is enabled (Standard or Enterprise)

Comment: Perfect - follow up question: is there a way to 'downgrade' from Enterprise to Standard? The radio buttons are disabled on the "Enable Enterprise Features" page.

Comment: I think this is still valid for 2013, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33131/downgrade-sharepoint-2010-from-enterprise-to-standard, so no it is not possible. Please mark as answer if answered the question

Comment: Now that the required time limit for marking a reply as the answer has passed, I have done so. Thank you.

Comment: Hehe, just to many times people forget it after getting the answer the wants ;)